# What is the origin of "tja"?

Tags: etymology, interjection

It seems to me that "tja" is more a typo for "ja" than a word by its own.

I have looked in a number of websites, the only satisfying one was [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tja) but it has nothing about its etymology as a German word.

How did the word "tja" originate?

Comment: Probably a Dutch origin. I've heard it more in the Netherlands than here in Germany. But perhaps I'm just being biased.

Comment: Hmmm... it could be I guessed right. "Tja" comes from "ja", when you stress the "j", like "Dschungel" from "jungle". In Dutch, there are other examples, e.g. "tjonge" and "sjonge" from "jongen" (boy), meaning: "oh boy". The meaning of "tja" then also changed to the current one ("nun ja", "nou ja", "well yes"). It could even come from an Indonesian Dutch dialect, where people spoke Dutch "ja" as "tja". In Dutch, it is often repeated, like tja-ja or tjonge-jonge.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Pure Lautähnlichkeit kann auch irreführend sein - Demnach könnte das Wort auch aus dem Schwedischen kommen, wo es ein *Tja* gibt, das ganz einfach "Hallo" heißt (eine Verkürzung von "Tjänare", was soviel wie "bin dein Diener" bedeutet). Und ich gehe eine Wette ein, dass es die Laute in Mandarin auch gibt ;)

Comment: Im Niederländischen hat "tja" die exakt gleiche Bedeutung. Und die Herleitung ist nicht von mir, sondern aus einem Wörterbuch. Und die da gegebene Erklärung ist enorm plausibel, vor allem weil das auch mit anderen j-Wörtern passiert ist, z.B. tjonge, tjeminee (von jeminee = herrje), etc. Es kann übrigens auch ein S ein: sja, sjonge, sjeminee, was wieder von der französichen Aussprache von J kommen könnte (wie in "jeune", "juge", "Jules", etc.)

Comment: Da "Tja" in mündlicher Rede viel häufiger als in schriftlicher ist scheidet ein Typo aus, wie auch die hier gängigen Tastaturlayouts keinen Ansatzpunkt für eine Tippfehlerhypothese bilden.

Comment: FWIW, it more or less translates as one of the meanings of *well*, e.g. "well, things like that happen": "tja, so was passiert" or "tja, da hattest du Pech": "well, that was bad luck".

Answer (score 6):

"tja" is an interjection ([Interjektion](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Interjektion)). Like "oh", "ah" or "pst". I wouldn't consider it as a word which has developed from something.

You could also say "nun ja", but what does that really mean? Just filling words or a filling sound to bridge the silence till your thoughts caught up.

I doubt it originated from a typo, because it is used mainly in spoken German. It get from there into the literary language. And it sounds better as "uhm" "ähm" or "äh", but fulfills the same purpose.

Comment: Note that the word is also found in other languages, especially Dutch.

Answer (score 4):

"Tja" is more than a typo for "ja", Like when somebody lost her mobile:

> Her : "Ich hab mein Handy verloren."
>   Me : "Tja da kann man nix machen"

You can't put in "ja" there. Mostly used when expressing "Schicksal/Kismet"

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I know "tja" and "ja" cannot be used interchangeably, I just guess "tja" was made of a typo when talking about its origin.

Comment: Ok. I still don't think tja originated from a typo. ;-)

Comment: While I also don't think it originated from a typo, *ja* could be used in this example. Maybe this becomes clearer when the comma that belongs there is added: "Ja, da kann man nix machen" / "Tja, da kann man nix machen".

Comment: Ja doesn't transport the implication of tough luck. Ja, da kann man nix machen = Yes you can't do anything about it.Tja, da kann man nix machen. = Yes you can't do anything about it, it's just tough luck/Kismet/Schicksal.

Comment: @PortreeKid Add a shrug of the shoulders, and even the *ja* can be used in a resignative way.

Comment: But don't forget the second part of the sentence. Otherwise it's Ja, und? ;-)

Answer (score -3):

My opinion:
tja = shortened 'Du, ja',
whereas both 'du' (= you) and 'ja' (= yes) 
are used as stresses.

For example:

> 'Du – Krieg ist halt schrecklich!'
>
> 'Ja – weißt du – Krieg ist halt schrecklich!'
>
> = 'Tja – Krieg ...'